# IAM CreateTable permission for one database only on Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have a group to which I'd like to grant `CreateTable` permissions on one database in Athena, while applying lesser permissions such as `RunQuery` on all databases to the same group. Is it possible to apply permissions to Athena databases on a case by case basis?

For example, in the below IAM policy I'd like to give this group the ability to create and delete tables in the test database.

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "athena:RunQuery",
                "athena:StartQueryExecution",
                "athena:StopQueryExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"  // Apply these permissions on all schemas
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "glue:CreateTable",
                "glue:DeleteTable"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "test"   // Apply these permissions to only the test database
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The IAM documentation for both services ([athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonathena.html), [glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsglue.html)) state that they have no service-specific resources or condition keys.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. From what my colleagues have told me I think you're right. If it's true I think it's a huge shortcoming of Athena, users who aren't in the right part of a business to have create table rights on the whole service can't even have a sandbox database to create tables in :'(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time you asked this question it was not possible to grant permissions to specific databases and tables, but it is now.

The permissions need to be granted on three levels: the catalog, the database, and the table (for table permissions, database permissions only need the two first).

Here is an example of how to grant create, update, and delete permissions to all tables in a database called `my_db` in account 1234567890 in us-east-1:

```
 {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "glue:CreateTable",
    "glue:UpdateTable",
    "glue:DeleteTable"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:1234567890:catalog",
    "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:1234567890:database/my_db",
    "arn:aws:glue:us-east-1:1234567890:table/my_db/*"
  ]
}
```

It's possible to use wildcards for the database name, or partial database name (for example if you want to grant some permissions to all databases with a specific prefix), and the same with table names.